# who to bind listviewcolumn header into a column cell in WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, binding

I have the following problem. I want to set a trigger binding it with the path=columnHeader

```
 <DataTrigger Binding="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ActualColumnHeader}" Value="1"/>
```

(i really dont know how to call this...)

my code is something like this:

```
<ListView Name="LV_Reporte" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="GV_Reporte">
                <GridViewColumn Header="Order1">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock.Style>
                                    <Style>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ActualColumnHeader}" Value="1">

                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </TextBlock.Style>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

but the problem is that i really don't know the header of the column, they will be created dynamically, that's why I want to get the header without knowing it.

I hope someone can help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use the `StringFormat` markup

```
  <GridViewColumn Header="Order1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Property1, StringFormat=Order1 {0}}"/>
```

Comment: but the problem is that i really dont know the column header, because im going to make they add dinamically, and i wanted to use the column name to set in a datatemplate